# How to get custom schema draft in json-schema-validator-1.0.68.jar?

Tags: java, json, jsonschema, jackson-databind, json-schema-validator

i am defining my custom schema draft in my json-schema.

```
{   "$schema": "http://oag.company.com/ver1/schema#",   
    "title": "JSON Identity Attribute Schema" 
}
```

and want to fetch it in code validation.
i am using  ***json-schema-validator-1.0.68.jar*** which comes with com.networknt.
my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonSchemaFactory schemaFactory = JsonSchemaFactory.getInstance();
        String exppath="exp.json";
        String schpath ="schm.json";
        try ( 
                InputStream jsonStream = new FileInputStream(exppath);
                InputStream schemaStream = new FileInputStream(schpath);
        ) {
            JsonNode json = objectMapper.readTree(jsonStream);
            com.networknt.schema.JsonSchema schema = schemaFactory.getSchema(schemaStream);
            Set<ValidationMessage> validationResult = schema.validate(json);
          
            if (validationResult.isEmpty()) {
                
                System.out.println("no validation errors :-)");
                System.out.println(json.path("FirstName"));
            } else {
                validationResult.forEach(vm -> System.out.println(vm));
            }
        }
    }
```

the error message i got is

> Exception in thread "main" com.networknt.schema.JsonSchemaException: Unknown MetaSchema: https://oag.oracle.com/ver1/schema

is thier any way so i can use my custom schema or can i use any other library which allow custom schema ?

Comment: Check the documentation for how to load additional schemas so they are known to the evaluator.

Comment: i have looked a lot but could not find relevant details,can you please provide me the link?

Comment: I think you're confusing different things. `$schema` is used as the meta-schema and dialect. I don't think you want that. It sounds like you want to download a schema from a specific URL and then use that as your JSON Schema to do validaiton. Just make a requst and process the response as a string to create your schema as per the quickstart guide in the libraries docs (on github)

Answer (score 1):

"$schema" is meta-version of the IETF standard, you need to refer your as "$ref".

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-{version}/schema#",
  "$ref": "http://oag.company.com/ver1/schema#"
}
```